# Is there preference settings so Google stops favoring recent news?

Tags: google-search

Doug Saunders ask, [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/DougSaunders/status/205271693827121152),

> Is there a way to turn off Google's recent-news precedence so it strictly searches by backlink count, as it used to do?

Comment: An example would help.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Google customize their search according to a lot of parameters, from language, origin country and location to personal interests etc.

If both of us will search the same phrase, we will get different results. If I'm not mistaken, it can be also in incognito mode.

The only way to get results strictly by backlink count is to use a search engine that doesn't optimize and customize results.

Comment: _"The only way to get results strictly by backlink count is to use a search engine that doesn't optimize and customize results."_ And those were terrible, because they were so easy to game by site owners.

Comment: Sad but true 